# Word for an elderly person with diminishing mental faculties

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What do you call an old person suffering from the loss of mental faculties?
According to the Oxford dictionary, [*dotard*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dotard) is an old person, especially one who has become weak or senile. But a weak or senile person does not necessarily show mental weakness and can be either mentally ill, or physically weak.

> More and more ____  are arriving in our retirement home these days. Please instruct the procurement manager to purchase additional PCs and printers to satisfy their needs.

Comment: The word *senile* does suggest mental weakness - e.g.loss of memory, inability to focus etc.  But it sounds to me as though the missing words you are looking for are *mentally active*. Otherwise, I think your question is not so much directly about the English language, as about care and understanding of the elderly.

Comment: Firstly, I have to say that your example sentence is a little odd since I can't imagine that the age and condition of the people you're trying to label would have a clamoring need for PCs and printers.  But anyway, a respectful term would be "seniors" or "senior citizens" and then you can add "with dementia"  or "suffering from Alzheimer's Disease".  *More and more senior citizens with dementia are arriving in our retirement home these days. Please instruct the procurement manager to purchase additional PCs and printers to satisfy their needs.*

Comment: @Kristina Lopez Thanks, but I want a single word for such people. I would prefer to use words like "mentally disabled" or "mentally disordered". Are these words polite for the elders?

Comment: @WS2 **you are looking for are mentally active**  What are retirement homes for? My context is about mentally disabled seniors who can use PC and also arrive in special institutions to get help.

Comment: Why is it necessary to call out their mental deficiencies when the point of the sentence is simply "we need more PCs"?  Unless the PCs are specially designed to accommodate people with mental illnesses.  ***Seniors*** is the preferred term here as Kristina suggests.

Comment: @Jim I think all this depends on exactly what type of home we are discussing. My father died last year, three months short of his 100th birthday. Over the last three years I spent a lot of time visiting his care home, which was divided into two sections - one containing people with a moderate amount of memory; and another one containing residents with very diminished memories. I never, at any time, saw any patient using a PC or printer.

Comment: @Jim Spot on! These PCs are specially designed for people with mental weaknesses and help such people to communicate with others.

Comment: @user128024 But these must be for patients in a very early phase of memory loss.

Comment: @WS2 I am sorry about the passing of your father.

Comment: Why do you need to label them as "suffering from the loss of mental faculties?"  Especially in a memo to people who already know the condition of these people.  Why can't you call them patients, guests, residents, etc?  It's like saying "More sick people are coming to the hospital so we need more supplies."  Do you need to say "sick". Who else comes to the hospital for care?

Comment: The nursing home where my sis-in-law's father resided referred to these residents as "Memory Care" residents.  Basically, the "Memory Care" section had special ID badges for the residents that alerted staff if they left the unit - for their own protection.

Comment: @KristinaLopez The one where my father was resident, and where his lady friend of 30 years remains, has designated its Alzheimer's wing *Memory Lane* - a very secure area.  But there are many different conditions of dementia. In his case his memory was not totally lost, but he became paranoid and thoroughly confused.

Comment: I think OP has misunderstood the meaning of ***dotard***. It's related to ***dotage***, which the *full* OED defines as *The state of one who dotes or has the **intellect impaired,** now esp. through old age; **feebleness or incapacity of mind or understanding;** infatuation, folly; second childhood; senility.* That's to say it's very specifically about diminished *mental*, not physical capabilities.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez's suggestion is the most respectful and politically correct: [*More and more senior citizens with dementia are arriving...*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270994/word-for-an-elder-with-mental-weakness#comment598272_270994). Please post your suggestion!

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/social-care-network/2015/jun/11/why-are-nursing-homes-worse-than-care-homes The elderly who are looked after in these care institutions (in the UK) are sometimes referred to as *residents*. "senior citizens" is mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elderly_care

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT - Feb 16th, 2023**
From several newspaper on this date:

1. Bruce Willis has dementia, his family announces.  [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/entertainment-arts-64670521)
2. Hollywood star Bruce Willis diagnosed with dementia. [9NEWS](https://www.9news.com.au/world/bruce-willis-diagnosed-with-dementia/e30f3365-f15b-459e-8dd0-be1b9e870cb6)

Several other sources quote "he has been diagnosed **with dementia**". and my Google search produced no results for "is demented". I, therefore, agree that we're much safer with **"has dementia"** or "is **"suffering from dementia"** rather than "is demented".

**FORMER ANSWER - SEPT. 2015**
Dementia is the general term when you refer to cognitive impairment of the aged. There are several kinds, the best known perhaps Alzheimer's Disease, of which we can find several degrees. **The adjective you are looking for is "demented".** (...more and more, demented elderly are arriving...)

> - demented - suffering from dementia.
> - dementia is a general term for a decline in mental ability severe enough to interfere with daily life. Memory loss is an example. Alzheimer's is the most common type of dementia.  Dementia is not a specific disease. It's an overall term that describes a wide range of symptoms associated with a decline in memory or other thinking skills severe enough to reduce a person's ability to perform everyday activities. Alzheimer's disease accounts for 60 to 80 percent of cases. Vascular dementia, which occurs after a stroke, is the second most common dementia type. But there are many other conditions that can cause symptoms of dementia, including some that are reversible, such as thyroid problems and vitamin deficiencies. **Dementia is often incorrectly referred to as "senility" or "senile dementia," which reflects the formerly widespread but incorrect belief that serious mental decline is a normal part of aging.**
>   from [alzheimer's association.org](http://www.alz.org/what-is-dementia.asp)

Examples from The New England Journal of Medicine - section, [letters](http://www.nejm.org/search?q=demented):

> - "My 90-year-old, demented paternal grandmother seemed to be having a stroke..."
> - "I have a patient whose demented husband no longer recognizes her."
> - ". At the time of the initial hospital interview, 1 patient was too demented to respond."
> - " Yet some demented patients, in particular, may seem to derive continued enjoyment from life."
> - "Many patients with the acquired immunodeficiency syndrome (AIDS) become demented."
> - "myoclonic movements in a demented patient with mid-life familial **Alzheimer's disease** may also suggest Huntington's disease."

Comment: The source you're quoting from doesn't have the term *demented* in its page, and with good reason too! It's a very derogative term, and to call an elderly person "demented" is akin to saying they are insane/mad/crazy etc. which may even  be true but it's an inappropriate word for any institution  that specializes in the care of the elderly and the infirm.

Comment: Not my downvote, and I'm not angry. I'm being helpful. Find a medical source that refer to elderly people with Alzheimer as *demented*, and I'll upvote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There you are.

Comment: Although technically correct, I also do not feel *demented* is the right word to use. However, I feel *dementia sufferers* is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @jxh Some words used to be pejorative.  Nowadays if a patient is demented, that's the right word to use. Just like cancer half a century ago, some people would avoid the word altogether ("something serious" or "that disease"would often substitute) Doctors now are more frank with  patients and avoid hiding anything, except in special cases when it's obvious the patient won't understand or has no emotional condition to be told the truth. Of course if a patient has advanced dementia, it's no use telling him the diagnosis  But there is nothing wrong telling his family members and using the word.

Comment: I think we agree the goal is clear communication. While I personally would not find offense with the use of *demented*, I understand that its expression is rather cold. It describes the state of the person in a matter of fact way, and fails to convey the other problems surrounding the condition beyond the disease itself. Surely the patient and their loved ones would appreciate even lip service attention to that point.

Comment: @jxh Yes, respect to one's feelings is number one rule.

Comment: *Nowadays if a patient is demented, that's the right word to use.* I doubt that was true seven years ago, and it is definitely not now. Please search `demented pejorative`.

Comment: Why not put your recent edit at the top of the answer, given what your search returned?

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[senility](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/senility)*** is the appropriate  term:

> - Relating to or having diminished cognitive function, as when memory is impaired, because of old age.

I think that you need to express the concept with a phrase rather than a single word. One possible option is:

- More and  more *aged people who suffer from senility* are arriving in our retirement home these days.

Comment: FWIW, my generation and my parents'  grew up using the word "senile" to describe the condition that is now referred to as either "dementia" or Alzheimer's Disease.  According to the Alzheimer's sites (both US and UK), "senility" is an outdated word replaced by the more accurate term of "dementia".  Apparently along with the current disfavor of using "senility" is the notion that cognitive decline is a natural part of aging, which apparently it is not.

Comment: @kristina - dementia sounds 'offensive' to me, but you are probably right as medical usage.

Comment: I know what you mean, Josh...because I think of "demented" when I hear "dementia".  I guess I'm used to it now because of the onslaught of medical news we're exposed to today.

Answer (score 1):

At Mari-Lou's kind suggestion that I post my comment as an answer:

*More and more **senior citizens with dementia** are arriving in our retirement home these days. Please instruct the procurement manager to purchase additional PCs and printers to satisfy their needs.*

Comment: I often hear the terms *guests*, *patients*, or *residents* when referring to nursing or convalescent homes but Wiki also suggests "senior citizens" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elderly_care

Comment: This was pretty good, but seven+ years later . . . I would suggest: *More and more seniors experiencing cognitive decline are arriving in our retirement home these days.*

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's comments, I believe it would be better to describe the type of equipment being sought rather than the people needing the equipment.

There is a sub-field within *Occupational Therapy* called **Adaptive Technology** which concerns itself with finding (among other things) hardware and software that make it easier for people with various special needs to use, for example, computers.  The most common difficulties that arise have to do with low vision and lack of familiarity.

> Please instruct the procurement manager to confer with the occupational therapist and purchase additional PCs and printers to satisfy the new residents' **adaptive technology** needs.